# AJAX post onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to figure out why I get the result I do when I post with my ajax code.

As you can see, on most things in my form I use `onchange="mySubmit(this.form)"` or `onclick="mySubmit(this.form)"` to submit my form with ajax, so this works for the input elements, it returns all the right divs and stuff into my div that is supposed to show all the data thats returned.

However, in my `<li>` at the bottom of the `form`I also have `onclick="mySubmit(this.form)"`, but it doesn't work, it for some reason displays my whole page inside the div that will display my data, which imo is quite weird, can I somehow post onclick any other way with my `<li>`?

**HTML** code :

```
        <input type="text" name="inputDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
            onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@inputDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@placeholderStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

        <input type="text" name="endDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
            onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@endDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

        <select name="NormOrAvg" class="dwmViewSelect" onchange="mySubmit(this.form)">
            <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "1") value="1">Rep Per Set</option>
            <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "2") value="2">Average Rep Per Set</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="holdLiftMenu">
        <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid4" id="hid4" value="4" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a onclick="mySubmit(this.form)" class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid1" id="hid1" value="" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a onclick="mySubmit(this.form)" class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid2" id="hid2" value="" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a onclick="mySubmit(this.form)" class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid3" id="hid3" value="" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS** Ajax code:

```
function mySubmit(theForm) {
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think `this` won't be the form.. have you tried to console.log `theForm` variable?

Comment: hahahah same question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the `li` this last refer to element it self and this last does not have `form` attribute  which results undefined .

Replace all your `onchange/onclick="mySubmit(this.form)` by `onchange/onclick="mySubmit(this);` and also change your `mySubmit` function  to :

```
function mySubmit(theForm) {
    theForm = $(theForm).closest("form");
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
}
```

above sample snippet :

```js
function mySubmit(theForm) {
        console.log($(theForm).closest("form").attr("action"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="~/AJAXcalls/repinintAJAX.cshtml" name="form">

  <div class="holdLiftMenu">
        <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid4" id="hid4" value="4" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a onclick="mySubmit(this)" class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid1" id="hid1" value="" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a onclick="mySubmit(this)" class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid2" id="hid2" value="" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                <a onclick="mySubmit(this)" class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift
                    <input type="hidden" name="hid3" id="hid3" value="" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```